# REST Authentication cache for intranet API

Tags: rest, authentication, spring-security, ldap

I'm exposing a REST based API on an enterprise intranet to support both a web application and other services. For the web app, a cookie based solution meets my requirements. And for other services, basic authentication would do just fine.

But the trick is, users are authenticated against ldap and I don't want to hit ldap server for every service call. I wonder if there is any best practices for this kind of situations.

I'm using Spring (3.2) and other usual suspects, Spring Security, MVC, Hibernate...

Ldap authentication is a bit hairy so I'm using my own thing, maybe I might introduce some kind of cache in there.

Answer (score 0):

Do the LDAP lookup once. Your API can keep an in-memory cache of authenticated userIds. Have the cache entries stay valid for either a fixed amount of time or for an amount of time since the last call came in. Clients can still use the cookie or basic auth to send credentials.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm implying in the question, but you're talking about a manual solution right? Nothing provided by Spring or any other libraries?

Comment: I would either hand-roll the cache or use a Guava timed eviction cache: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Timed_Eviction . I'm not familiar with what Spring offers as far as caching goes.